# I need Windows 7 Back!

Tags: 12.10, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I’ve installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, but all the things I need are only on Windows 7

So I got a bootable USB of Windows XP , I tried to boot up from it , I saw the blinking dash which should be like a loading symbol but then GRUB tookover and like interrupted it. Same thing with Windows 7 and a release preview of 8

Is there a way to boot with the USBs into Windows Installer or Do I need a Windows 7 Installation Disk?

Please help , I need Windows for my school projects and my own personal gaming.

---

PS - I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a HP 2000 and I believe a 1.3GHz Multi-Core CPU with AMD Radeon Graphics chip.

PPS - I have tried removing Ubuntu totally (Gparted) and then I boot up with Windows bootable USB to TRY to do a clean install but then I get "Unknown File System , Grub Rescue>" then I have to do some dumb file commands